# Argument error while running chord in Celery

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, celery, chord

Here's my directory structure:

`` app
|-- automate-scan.py
|-- helpers
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- tasks.py
|   `-- tasks.pyc
|-- __init__.py
`-- __init__.pyc ``

Now here's what I am trying to run:

**atuomate_scan.py**

```
import os
from configobj import ConfigObj
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from kombu import Queue

celapp=Celery(backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='amqp://user:pass@localhost/my_vhost')
CELERY_CONFIG = {
    'CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE': 'default',
    'CELERY_QUEUES': (Queue('initialScanning'),),
    'CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER': 'pickle',
    'CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT': ['json','pickle']
}

celapp.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)

config_file = '/home/myuser/config.cfg'
config_obj = ConfigObj(config_file)
repo_list_file = config_obj.get('files').get('repo_file')

@celapp.task()
def run_scan(repo):
    print repo
    os.system("git clone " + repo)
    repo_to_scan = repo.split('/')[1].split('.')[0]
    os.system("python /home/someuser/myscript.py file:///home/someuser/repo_collection/" + repo_to_scan +  " --json --regex")

@celapp.task()
def final_task():
    print "hakuna matata"
```

*repositories* - in the below code is a list of strings
**tasks.py**

```
import os
from configobj import ConfigObj
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from kombu import Queue
from celery import chord
from helpers import tasks

f = open('/home/someuser/repositories.lst')
os.system("mkdir /home/someuser/repo_collection")
repositories = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

print repositories
print "\n\n"
created_task = (tasks.run_scan.subtask((repo)) for (repo) in repositories)
finaltask = tasks.final_task.subtask()
res = chord(created_task,queue='initialScanning')(finaltask)
```

When I run `automate-scan.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/automate-scan.py", line 20, in <module>
    res = chord(created_task,queue='initialScanning')(finaltask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1189, in __call__
    return self.apply_async((), {'body': body} if body else {}, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1232, in apply_async
    return self.run(tasks, body, args, task_id=task_id, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1277, in run
    header_result = header(*partial_args, task_id=group_id, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 953, in __call__
    return self.apply_async(partial_args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 978, in apply_async
    args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1054, in _apply_tasks
    **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 218, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 513, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: run_scan() takes exactly 1 argument (50 given)
```

I don't understand where am I giving 50 arguments. Please let me know where am I going wrong and what needs to be changed to fix this.

**Edit 1**
Also, I tried changing the line :

`created_task = (tasks.run_scan.subtask((repo)) for (repo) in repositories)`

to

```
created_task = (tasks.run_scan.subtask(repo) for repo in repositories)
```

as well. But the same results

Comment: One hint maybe is to split this call `chord(created_task,queue='initialScanning')(finaltask)` in two steps, like `res = chord(created_task,queue='initialScanning')` and then `res = res(finaltask)` in order to discover which one does trigger the error.

Comment: I wonder how would that help though. Nevertheless, I tried it and the results are still the same. Also, I tried changing the line 
`created_task = (tasks.run_scan.subtask((repo)) for (repo) in repositories)` to
`created_task = (tasks.run_scan.subtask(repo) for repo in repositories)`
as well. But the same results.

Comment: Of course the error is still here. The goal is only to discover more precisely where it comes from. As it shows up quite deeply buried in the celery code, this is a start to know whether the `chord()` call itself does trigger the error, or the call to the object returned by this `chord()` call. Now you know this, it would be good to edit your question to let others know.

Comment: @zezollo sure. That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Hum, we still don't know if the problem is already triggered by `res = chord(created_task,queue='initialScanning')` or the next line `res = res(final_task)`... this is maybe not enough but necessary to understand where the error comes from...